# Get input field value and redirect using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I wanna obtain input field data in a Javascript variable and perform a redirect.

```
<form onsubmit="someRandomFunction()">
<input type="search" name="search" id="search_bar" placeholder="Type a string">
</form>
```

Now, I have HTML files namely, xyz.html, abc.html, pqrs.html etc..
I want the user to get redirected on the page whose name he types.. For example, searching for the string pqrs should redirect the user to pqrs.html.. Please help me with the code for the Javascript function..

Comment: Try some code first. Post what you've done we can then help you find bugs. But don't ask us to write your whole code for you - that's just cheeky.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answer, but unfortunately it ain't working for me..
P.S. I'm sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using jQuery Mobile..

Answer (score 0):

using [window.location.href](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

```
function someRandomFunction(){
     window.location.href = document.getElementById("search_bar").value + ".html";
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet.

```
function someRandomFunction()
{
    window.location.pathname = '/'+document.getElementById('search_bar').value+'.html';
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/gfc7m043/)**.

Here is the snippet.

```js
function someRandomfunction() {
  var page = document.getElementById('search_bar').value;;
  location.href = page + '.html';
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return someRandomFunction()">
  <input type="search" name="search" id="search_bar" placeholder="Type a string" />
</form>
```